# FBSDKCoreKit.h not found error

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk

I have followed all the instructions for integrating fbsdk in iOS, as soon as I make build it is throwing error `FBSDKCoreKit.h` not found error in

> node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/core/RCTFBSDKGraphRequestManager.h:21:9:
>   'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found

I have configured it manually rather than pod

Comment: Have you ran react-native link?

Comment: Yes, I ran react-native link and even did the necessary settings in Info.plist and appDelegate.m for Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem, you can try use "react-native run-ios"  replace "npm run ios".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. -

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the frameworks under the RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj under libraries.

If not carefully follow the steps below. This programmer has highlight some of the common mistake when manually linking RCTFBSDK.

https://medium.com/@rachieb19/struggles-with-react-native-link-1f1738076472

[image]